# Spring Security bypass authentication if url has a %20 in it

Tags: java, spring

Somehow, we have a rest api that can be bypassed if it starts with a space.
The war is hosted by tomcat.

with this call, it passes through without authentication.
http://myserver/api/version/mywarapplication/%20admin/param1/param2/users

with this one, I do get the expected 403
http://myserver/api/version/mywarapplication/admin/param1/param2/users

The spring security config is like this for the mapping

```
.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/authenticate/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/checkCredentials/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/Downloads/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
```

The request mapping looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/{param1}/{param2}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, as I can't see what we're missing.

Comment: Does `%20admin` actually enter the given `RequestMapping`?

Comment: yes, which is why it's a problem.  I would've expected a 404.  But I think I figured out what might be happening, I'll check tomorrow.  We're on Spring 4.0.3, and until 4.3.0  white space are trimmed by default in the paths if I understand it.  So, Spring Security don't see it, but Spring gets it because of the trimming.  So Security isn't trimming the path to check the "authenticated" but spring does.  I'll try to change the rules to authenticate all and add exception instead of the current matches

Comment: You must have other rules in there which you have not shown. My advice would be to disallow everything, and then set paths which are accessible when logged in.